# Is a question requiring animated ASCII art acceptable?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions out there with ASCII art but I was thinking if a question requesting animated ASCII is acceptable? Problem is I don't think many golf languages support some sort of clear/redraw command for their output, so the users would be forced to use other languages.

That being said the question wouldn't be a golf question.

Comment: something like this? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18599/one-line-aquarium

Comment: One could always just output each frame of the animation in order, and require a specific console (or textbox) width/height to view the animation properly, in which clear/redraw is no longer required

Answer (score 16):

There's nothing wrong with that. Many golfing languages can't manipulate files or produce graphical output, yet we've had really great [file-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) and [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) challenges. While language-*specific* challenges are strongly discouraged, not every challenge has to be solvable in every language.

That said, [it's perfectly possible to clear/redraw the screen manually with nothing but ASCII characters](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5515/8478). Go for it!